# Joint state settlers crash when trying out to adapt robot calibration to custom robot

Tags: ros, robot-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

we´re currently working on adapting the available calibration package to work with a custom robot. We started with the maxwell_calibration package and made good progress (robot is moving into desired configurations, checkerboards are processed), but the joint states settlers crash with the following output:

```
    [ERROR] [1383211182.404871655, 1206.508000000]: Couldn't find mapping for [l_as_y]
    [ERROR] [1383211182.404943731, 1206.508000000]: Couldn't find mapping for [l_as_x]
    [ERROR] [1383211182.404961282, 1206.508000000]: Couldn't find mapping for [l_ae_y]
    [ERROR] [1383211182.404979138, 1206.508000000]: Couldn't find mapping for [l_ae_x]
    [ERROR] [1383211182.404995090, 1206.508000000]: Couldn't find mapping for [l_aw_y]
    [ERROR] [1383211182.405027718, 1206.508000000]: Couldn't find mapping for [l_aw_x]
[arm_chain/settler-2] process has died [pid 15860, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/joint_states_settler/joint_states_settler_action joint_states:=/joint_states __name:=settler __log:=/home/kohlbrecher/.ros/log/9732cc4c-420a-11e3-ab6a-0090f5e666cf/arm_chain-settler-2.log].
log file: /home/kohlbrecher/.ros/log/9732cc4c-420a-11e3-ab6a-0090f5e666cf/arm_chain-settler-2*.log
```

We didn´t do any major changes, essentially just renaming the joint names to reflect the actual robot configuration. For simplicity, we also did not rename the arm_chain. Any ideas what the problem could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96341/joint-state-settlers-crash-when-trying-out-to-adapt-robot-calibration-to-custom-robot/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok found the culprit: Had multiple different publishers to the "/joint_states" topic, which meant that the joints of interest to the settlers were not contained in some messages received. The settlers are apparently not robust against this and will crash.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1